# Java: Access modifier more restrictive than 'protected', less restrictive than 'private'?

Tags: java, subclass, private, protected, access-modifiers

I want something similar to `protected`, where only a class which implements the `protected` field and anything that subclasses it can access it.

So, I want to be able to declare a variable in the base class as `private`, but still be able to access it from a subclass.

Perhaps this is against the very nature of subclassing, `private`, and/or `protected`.

Does something like this exist in Java?

Comment: as a general rule, exposing variables is a bad idea - even to sub-classes.  There are exceptions, but I'd encourage you to think real hard about why you want to do this.  (I realize that the same question would apply to a getter method call - just wanted to point out a potential problem)

Comment: This functionality (although not this syntax) can be achieved through use of a protected getter method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are only four access levels for fields in Java:

- `private`
- package-private (default; no access modifier)
- `protected`
- `public`

`protected` will allow subclasses, other classes in the same package, and members in the class itself to access the `protected` member.

The short answer is, there is no way to achieve exactly what is desired.

For a description of those four access modifiers, [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) from [The Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html) has more specific information.

Answer (score 2):

If you control the codebase, you can always control what goes into the package with the baseclass - if it's alone in its package, only subclasses can access the member you want to keep private except for subclasses.

Comment: This is quite a good workaround. Al-thou it does not answer the question of is there a modifier like that (which is there is not) but does provide required functionality.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no [access modifier](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) to do exactly that.  The `protected` modifier is the closest thing, but that exposes the field to any class in the same package as well as to subclasses (in or out of the same package).

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. U can still declare your variables as private then declare public methods that modify the variables in
the superclass. You then call the public method on the variable.